# go from Pop_OS 19.10 to straight Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: upgrade

Is it possible to convert a functional Pop_OS 19.10 to a straight Ubuntu 19.10 without having to start fresh? How would I go about that? I see a lot of posts for going the other direction, from Ubuntu to Pop_OS; that is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The basic theory is that you would remove all packages from Pop_OS sources, then install a new desktop packages of your choice from Ubuntu sources. The first thing to learn is how to use apt, and how apt's sources work.

Comment: This question is specific to a release of Ubuntu which has reached its end of standard support or end of life date, and is not related to asking for help to upgrade to a supported release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would backup your system first, then (re-)install Ubuntu 19.10.

I would use the '*something else*' option, use existing partitions, and ensure you do **not** have format ticked for any partition.  In a Ubuntu re-install this will

- take note of your software packages installed
- wipe system directories
- install system
- add back your additional packages
- it won't touch user files/configs (as long as you don't format, and haven't put configs in system directories; most desktop configs are found in $HOME so not a big deal)

I have not used that with Pop OS, but it works with Ubuntu flavors, allowing you to change releases (jump from one release to another), change flavors (*usual effects of changing from one flavor to another should occur with a Pop (GNOME) to Ubuntu (GNOME) anyway*)

It's easy, and actually pretty fast. Feedback from 18.04 found the average install took about 17 minutes; this will only add a couple of minutes due to re-addition of your prior added packages.

Note:   Whilst I haven't done this, I would reduce your sources.list files to pure Ubuntu prior to this re-install. I don't know if it's necessary, but Pop OS will use higher package versions than Ubuntu so to ensure a Pop system stays Pop, which can cause issues if those sources remain; thus why I'd do this step. It may not be necessary (*if you skip it, at worst you'll need to do it, then re-install again*).